# Optimize mysql update million rows

Tags: mysql, node.js

What is the best way to update 15 millions records?
I need to update a sequence column that contains indexes going to 4096 and back to zero again to a normal unlimited sequence.

I could calculate the new sequence_id for each row like this, but this involves anode script sending 15 million Update requests in a very short period of time.

```
db.query("SELECT * from fridgeSensors ORDER BY id ASC", (err, devices, fields) =>
{
    devices.forEach(device => 
    { 
        db.query("SELECT * from fridgeEntries WHERE deviceID = '?' ORDER BY id ASC",[device.deviceID], (err, entries, fields) =>
        {
            var prev_seq = 0;
            entries.forEach(entry => 
                {
                    var seq = entry.seqNumber || 0;

                seq = (Math.floor(prev_seq/4096)*4096)+seq;
                if(seq < prev_seq) seq += 4096;


                db.query("UPDATE `fridgeEntries` SET `seqNumber`= ? WHERE `id`= ?;",[seq,entry.id]);

                prev_seq = sec;

            });
    });
});

});
```

I was thinking to send an insert.. on duplicate update with all new values for the column and the id primary key, but this means sending a very long request, considering each row would be about 20 characters inside the request 
`('xxxxxxx','xxxxxxx')`

This means a request with 300 Million characters...

Neither solutions sounds correct.
Any idea how this is supposed to be done?

node process and mysql are **not** on the same server

Comment: Why not just do something like `$seqNumber = $id % 4096` in your application?

Comment: My gut feeling is that there's a single update statement that can be executed to manage the "Set" as a whole.  But even so, updating 15 million records is going to take a bit simply becuase of the rollback logic.

Comment: @ceejayoz Because the new value is not based on he current row, but the previous row

Comment: @VincentDuprez `$seqNumber = ($id % 4096) + 1`, then?

Answer (score 0):

This a quick solution. I don't want to dive into seq calculation.

Create a table `tmp_seq` with `deviceID` and `seq` columns and fill it via one long query with multiply insertion, e.g `insert into tmp_seq (deviceId, seq) VALUES (1,2),(2,3),(7,8), ...`
Then execute `update fridgeEntries set seq = (select seq from tmp_seq tmp where tmp.deviceID = fridgeEntries.deviceID)`.

P.S. I assume that `DeviceID` is a key. Otherwise, you should use appropriate columns.